# Java: Checking each space in a String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm sure this is fairly simple, however I've tried googling the question but can't find an answer that fits my problem.

I'm playing around with string manipulation and one of the things I'm trying to do is get the first letter of each word. (And then place them all into a string)

I'm having trouble with registering each 'space' so that my If statement will be triggered. Here's what I have so far.

```
while (scanText.hasNext()) {
        boolean isSpace = false;
        if (scanText.hasNext(" ")) {isSpace = true;}

        String s = scanText.next();

        if (isSpace) {firstLetters += s + " ";}
    }
```

Also, if there is a much better way to do this then please let me know

Comment: White space is probably consumed by the `Scanner`, as it's using white space as word delimiter. You should check some other string to get white space in input or probably you don't need to take space from the input at all, just add it the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also split the original text by spaces, and collect the words.

```
String input = "    Hello world    aaa     ";
String[] split = input.trim().split("\\s+"); // all types of whitespace; " +" to pick spaces only
// operate on "split" array containing words now: [Hello, world, aaa]
```

However using regexps here might be overkill.

Comment: I managed to work out a solution on my own; would there be any disadvantages to doing it this way? Sorry, I can't format it well in the comment.    

    private static String firstLetters(String original) {
  Scanner scanText = new Scanner(original);
  String firstLetters = "";

  while (scanText.hasNext()) {
   String word = scanText.next();
   firstLetters += word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + " ";
  }
  
  scanText.close();
  return firstLetters;
    }

Comment: It's okay. Personally I'd replace firstLetters addition with firstLetters += Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + " "; to get rid of substring (because I think that _charAt_ evokes the intent better).


Later on you might want to read about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html, that provides cheaper string concatenation (you do not construct in-between Strings all the time).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that scanText is a Scanner object, you could use something like stated on the documentation:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s+"); //regex for spaces
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html